# using join in sql to get data from the third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in the following structure:

```
Car-Owners                            CarRecords                           Cars

ownerName  ownerID                 ownerID   carID                     carID   carName
```

I want to to list down all owners who own a specific car(say honda civic) and display the car name along with the owners name. I'm not so good with the JOIN statement and I can't seem to connect the dots on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

So what you might want to do is something like this:

```
select Car-Owners ownerName, Cars carName 
from Car-Owners, CarRecords, Cars 
 where Car-Owners.ownerId = CarRecords.ownerId 
 and CarRecords.carID = Cars.carId;
```

Technically this is an inner join just it's not explicit.

Comment: Technically this is old syntax, that you shouldn't use anymore

Comment: they are deprecating the implicit outer join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CO.ownerName, C.carName
FROM Car-Owners AS CO
INNER JOIN CarRecords CR ON CO.ownderID = CR.ownerID
INNER JOIN Cars C ON C.carID = CR.carID
WHERE carName = 'Delorean'
```

Comment: have you used Car-owners as CO?

Comment: Where C.carName = 'Talbot Princess'. Not an issue in this case but it's a good idea to qualify all your column names when doing joins.